# Run time error during a for loop

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to loop through a set of columns thereby counting the times the values "PAS" or "VRIJ" occur.

Therefore I wrote the following code:

```
  Sub CountWorkDays()

   Dim count As Integer
   count = 0

   For i = 1 To 6

   Dim var1 As Characters
   var1 = Cells(1, i).Value

   If var1 = "Test" Then
    count = count + 1

   ElseIf var1 = "PAS" Then
   count = count + 1

End If

Next
End

MsgBox (count)

End Sub
```

But when I run the code I get the following error:

```
 Run-time error '91':
 Object-variable or with block variable is not set
```

Tried googling the error but cant undestand where it's coming from. Any thoughts on how I should I improve the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set var1 as Characters - set it as a String instead and move the DIM line outside of the loop and get rid of the END statement - code execution stops there.

```
Sub CountWorkDays()

    Dim var1 As String
    Dim count As Integer
    count = 0

    For i = 1 To 6
        var1 = Cells(1, i).Value
        If var1 = "Test" Then
            count = count + 1
        ElseIf var1 = "PAS" Then
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next i

    MsgBox (count)

End Sub
```

Edit:
This may be a better way of doing it though:

```
Sub CountWorkDays()

    MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:A6"), "Test") + _
            Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:A6"), "PAS")

End Sub
```